# How to work with MediaPipe Multi-class selfie segmentation model?

Tags: javascript, html, deep-learning, mediapipe

I am working with MediaPipe library and wanted to detect hair and clothes from image. On their website, they gave good example and you can download and run the code. However, I want that when I detect hair or clothes, that area will become white and all other area remain same. However, MediaPipe only gave an example with "DeepLab-v3" model. Here you can see their example.

https://github.com/googlesamples/mediapipe/tree/main/examples/image_segmentation/js
https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/image_segmenter/index#models

This is their callback function and I want to detect hair or clothes and make them white.

```
function callback(result) {
    const cxt = canvasClick.getContext("2d");
    const { width, height } = result.categoryMask;

    let imageData = cxt.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;

    canvasClick.width = width;
    canvasClick.height = height;
    let category = "";

    const mask = result.categoryMask.getAsUint8Array();

    for (let i in mask) {
        if (mask[i] > 0) {
            category = labels[mask[i]];
        }
        const legendColor = legendColors[mask[i] % legendColors.length];
        imageData[i * 4] = (legendColor[0] + imageData[i * 4]) / 2;
        imageData[i * 4 + 1] = (legendColor[1] + imageData[i * 4 + 1]) / 2;
        imageData[i * 4 + 2] = (legendColor[2] + imageData[i * 4 + 2]) / 2;
        imageData[i * 4 + 3] = (legendColor[3] + imageData[i * 4 + 3]) / 2;
    }
    
    const uint8Array = new Uint8ClampedArray(imageData.buffer);
    const dataNew = new ImageData(uint8Array, width, height);
    cxt.putImageData(dataNew, 0, 0);
    const p = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("classification")[0];
    p.classList.remove("removed");
    p.innerText = "Category: " + category;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select a different model as given in the example code below:

```
const createImageSegmenter = async () => {
const vision = await FilesetResolver.forVisionTasks("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision@0.10.0/wasm");
imageSegmenter = await ImageSegmenter.createFromOptions(vision, {
    baseOptions: {
        modelAssetPath: "./path/to/selfie_multiclass.tflite", // Download the selfie multiclass model from their website or get the CDN URL
        delegate: "GPU"
    },
    runningMode: "IMAGE",
    outputCategoryMask: true,
    outputConfidenceMasks: true
});
labels = imageSegmenter.getLabels(); // this gives all the labels present in the model
};
```

And then in your code make the following changes:

```
function callback(result) {
const cxt = canvasClick.getContext("2d");
const { width, height } = result.categoryMask;

let imageData = cxt.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;

canvasClick.width = width;
canvasClick.height = height;
let category = "";

const mask = result.categoryMask.getAsUint8Array();

for (let i in mask) {
    if (mask[i] > 0) {
        category = labels[mask[i]];
    }
    if (category=="hair" || category=="clothes") {   // draw segmentation masks only for the category you want
    const legendColor = legendColors[mask[i] % legendColors.length];
    imageData[i * 4] = (legendColor[0] + imageData[i * 4]) / 2;
    imageData[i * 4 + 1] = (legendColor[1] + imageData[i * 4 + 1]) / 2;
    imageData[i * 4 + 2] = (legendColor[2] + imageData[i * 4 + 2]) / 2;
    imageData[i * 4 + 3] = (legendColor[3] + imageData[i * 4 + 3]) / 2;
   }
}

const uint8Array = new Uint8ClampedArray(imageData.buffer);
const dataNew = new ImageData(uint8Array, width, height);
cxt.putImageData(dataNew, 0, 0);
const p = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("classification")[0];
p.classList.remove("removed");
p.innerText = "Category: " + category;
}
```

In the legendColors variable, you can give the RGBA value of the color of the mask you would like to draw on the selected area.

The classes/labels in the selfie multiclass models are as below:

- 0 - background
- 1 - hair
- 2 - body-skin
- 3 - face-skin
- 4 - clothes
- 5 - others (accessories)

You can find more information regarding the model on their website: [[Link]](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/image_segmenter)

Comment: Is it possible not to use CDN and used node.js library. There is no example on their website.

Comment: Yes, you can install the task-vision package using NPM (npm install @mediapipe/tasks-vision), and then import it like : import vision from "@mediapipe/tasks-vision"

Comment: The examples on their website are limited, but if you Google search, other people have done projects on Mediapipe Image segmentation or Face landmarks model, their code will give you more ideas on how you can customize the code.